# Retrieve the image in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have upload controller to upload images. file_view is the html file where I used to upload my image and upload_success is the file where I used to retrieve file. In the upload_success file output appears like this

```
file_name: images.jpg
file_type: image/jpeg
file_path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Test/uploads/
full_path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Test/uploads/images.jpg
raw_name: images
orig_name: images.jpg
client_name: images.jpg
file_ext: .jpg
file_size: 10.65
is_image: 1
image_width: 218
image_height: 232
image_type: jpeg
image_size_str: width="218" height="232"
```

Can someone help me to view the image using  tag?

Controller

```
 <?php
        if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        class Upload_Controller extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
            public function index(){
                $this->load->view('file_view', array(
                    'error' => ' '
                ));
            }
            public function file_view()
            {
                $this->load->view('file_view', array(
                    'error' => ' '
                ));
            }
            public function do_upload()
            {
                $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
                    'overwrite' => TRUE,
                    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                    'max_height' => "768",
                    'max_width' => "1024"
                );
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $data = array(
                        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                } else {
                    $error = array(
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                    );
                    $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

File_view

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<!-- Error Message will show up here -->
<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'upload_controller/do_upload');?>
<?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
<?php echo "</form>"?>
```

upload_success

```
<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $item;?>:
                    <?php echo $value;?>

            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>

            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/').$upload_data['file_name'] ?>">

            </li>

    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
    </p>
```

Comment: Mr. Riaz thanks for your help.But this also doesn't retrieve the image path is correct but image do not preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
<!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $item;?>:
            <img src="<?php echo $value;?>">
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<p>
    <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this to view file

```
<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
<img src="<?php echo upload_data['full_path']; ?>">
<?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
```

Hope so this will help you.

Comment: thank you Akshay..but upload_data should be $upload_data

Comment: Yes, for this code. you can change the variable name, but in both the end

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer

```
<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>
    <!-- Uploaded file specification will show up here -->
    <ul>

            <li>


            </li>
            <img alt="Your uploaded image" src="<?=base_url(). 'uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name'];?>">

    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload_controller/file_view', 'Upload Another File!'); ?>
    </p>
```